# Creating a Real time update in Mobile Apps

Tags: php, android, ios

I want my app to be notified immediately whenever I update my server database.

From what I understand, we need the mobile to send a REQUEST to server to initiate any connection.

What I want is the server to be the communication starter not the mobile.

I am trying to avoid opening a channel, where the mobile keeps pinging the server every few milli seconds searching for an update.

I am hoping for a solution using PHP.

Is this possible? I dont need a code, I can write my own. I want the theory behind it, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) message to your android device and have it sync with your database.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#s2s

Here is the [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use either `Pusher` or `PubNub`. They are both server based push messaging platforms that have client APIs for iOS and Android and many server side APIs (including PHP).

I would not recommend using `GCM` (Google Cloud Manager) or `APNS` (Apple Push Notification Service) for this type of functionality. The problem is that message delivery is not guaranteed and you can not verify if the message was received. The user could decline to receive push notifications, or the services could decline to send the message if you sent too many (and not tell you). GCM and APNS are not meant for this type of usage.

The push notification services I recommend are inexpensive, but not free (although they both have free tiers to get you going). If you are unwilling to pay for a reliable push message delivery platform then you can investigate how those services work (there is plenty of documentation out there on the protocols/methodology they use) and write your own. But that is a whole lot of work to save a little.